# css: positioning of text and selectbox with css only

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

What's the best way to position text and selectbox horizontally as 25% + 50% + 25% with css only?

That's what we have:

```
<div id="mydiv">TextLeft <select id="myselectbox">...</select> TextRight</div>
```

We want TextLeft is centered in the left 25% of area (width can be changed),
so that TextRight is centered in the right 25% of area,
and `<select id="myselectbox">...</select>` is centered.

**CSS only please, if possible.**

Thank you.

Comment: If you want the CSS to update and change the position of your text dynamically, as the page changes, that's rather impossible JUST using CSS.  CSS is not a conditional, running in the background, language.  That's what JaveScript is for.

Comment: add `span` for text then it will be easier to handle the elements in css.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Why? http://jsfiddle.net/QjvMj/

Comment: @Atal Shrivastava Why spans, not divs then?

Comment: Spans are inline while divs are block, meaning spans go from left to right where as divs create paragraphs. @AtalShrivastava is correct.

Comment: That would depend on the contents, wouldn't it? Spans for pure text, divs if there's a chance they will contain block level elements.. May I suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/ymm9Z/

Comment: yup it matters of inline and block level elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not enough structure to do what you're asking in your HTML. As Atal mentioned, you could add spans to handle it like so: http://jsfiddle.net/wq35T/

Make the spans inline block to hold their width with a margin fix to keep them on the same line. There are other ways to solve this, but this is probably the cleanest code with no floats.

Edit: Not IE6/7 happy.

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span>TextLeft</span>
    <select id="myselectbox">...</select>
    <span>TextRight</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mydiv {
    text-align:center;
}

#mydiv > span {
    width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:-4px;
    text-align:center;
}

#myselectbox {
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Hoping i'am not late but you solved this with a ease @Andrew Clody